# Can I get the document key right after it is created?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Right after adding this data, I would like to have the reference of this document.

it is possible?

```
await userCycleCollectionRef.doc().set({
    userUid,
    startDate,
    endDate,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userCycleCollectionRef.doc()` returns a DocumentReference immediately, as you can see from the [API documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc).

```
const ref = userCycleCollectionRef.doc()
await ref.set({
    userUid,
    startDate,
    endDate,
});
```

Comment: I was looking in the https://rnfirebase.io/ documentation.


When should you look at the documentation for the base of the api.


I really love this stackoverflow, this beautiful community.


Thank you very much for the information.